# Im modeling a Aircraft(Mig9) but i don't know how to procced with the cockpit

Tags: modeling

As the title says
[image]

Im a newbie and im not sure how to model the cockpit of the aircraft. Im not looking for a super detailed cockpit but not a low poly as well.

Comment: This really isn't a question. You could watch a tutorial...

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch/follow any "make a car in blender tutorial" and you will know how to make the cockpit of your plane.

try (Modeling a Car: Honda HSV-010 GT): 
http://darkscarab.com/view/43